# How to save a domain with a hasMany property in gorm-hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, relationship

I have a User with hasMany UserRoles but when i try to save a User and addToRole there is a validation error during save i cant understand why.

```
class User ... {

static hasMany = [roles:UserRoles]


}
```

then i have a domain UserRoles

```
class UserRoles ... {

 Roles role 
 static  belongsTo = [user: User]


    UserRoles(Role r){
        role = r
    }


 }
```

And the Role domain looks like this

```
 class Role ... {


 String name

    Role(String name) {
        this.name = authority
    }


 }
```

Now when i try to save the User

I have a code like this

```
Role r = findRole()
user.addToRoles(roles: new UserRole(r))
user.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

but it returns an error saying

```
Field error in object 'com.api.v1.User' on field 'roles': rejected value [[Ljava.lang.String;@5871447d]; codes [com.api.v1.User.roles.typeMismatch.error,com.api.v1.User.roles.typeMismatch,user.roles.typeMismatch.error,user.roles.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.com.api.v1.User.roles,typeMismatch.roles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [roles]; default message [Could not find matching constructor for: com.api.v1.UserRoles(java.lang.String)]
```

Comment: What is your question?
The error is caused by a missing constructor in the `UserRole` class - like the error says. 
I guess, that the error is caused by your non empty constructors. 
Use map constructor instead as suggested in http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#basicCRUD

Answer (score 0):

u hav wrong input of fct addToRoles()

```
Role r = findRole()
--//user.addToRoles(roles: new User(r))
//++
user.addToRoles(roles: r)
user.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```